# ruby call method with double splash parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've got a legacy helper method defined as:

```
def feature(label, style = 'text', inverse: false, **html_options)
```

called by another helper that calls it with:

```
def create_feature(level, html_options = {})
  label, value = .....
  feature(label, value, html_options)
end
```

where in my instance:

```
(byebug) label
"In progress"
(byebug) value
:pending
(byebug) html_options
{ "data-value"=>"pending", :class=>"mr-2"}
```

I call this in the view I'm editing (the only bit of code I'm happy to modify in this instance):

```
<%= create_feature(level, my_helper(:pending).merge({class: 'mr-2'})) %>
```

where `my_helper` generates the `data-value: pending` attribute for the html element.

the previous version of this code was:

```
<%= create_feature(level, class: 'mr-2') %>
```

which worked, I need now to add the hash with the extra attribute from the `my_helper` but all I get is:

```
*** ArgumentError Exception: wrong number of arguments (given 3, expected 1..2)
```

oddly I created a dummy version of the same code, and it works just fine:

```
  def feature(label, style = 'text', inverse: false, **html_options)
    pp html_options
  end

 def create_feature(level, html_options = {})
    label, value = ['in progress', :pending]
    feature(label, value, html_options)
  end

create_feature(12, {hello: 'hello', class: 'mr-2'})
# {:hello=>"hello", :class=>"mr-2"}
```

Comment: _"I created a dummy version of the same code, and it works just fine"_ – if so, the cause of the error is outside the code you have shown. Take a close look at the error message and its stack trace. Maybe there's another method call you're missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the issue, it's not documented, but the hash passed in the splash parameter need to have all symbols as keys. Strings won't do.

So what I had to do is to call the method and use `.symbolize_keys` in the parameter.

I find this a bit annoying, because you are forced to remember this implementation detail in every call to a method with splash parameters. but this is how it is.

Answer (score 0):

Since the helper defines `html_options` as a "take all" [keyword argument](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/doc/syntax/methods_rdoc.html#label-Keyword+Arguments), you have to pass it as such:

```
def create_feature(level, html_options = {})
  label, value = .....
  feature(label, value, **html_options)
  #                     ^^
  #                  add this
end
```

The `**` operator will convert your [hash to keyword arguments](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/doc/syntax/calling_methods_rdoc.html#label-Hash+to+Keyword+Arguments+Conversion).

Comment: Thanks, I tried that, I get the very same error.

Comment: @DonGiulio the error message says _"given 3"_ (arguments) but `feature(label, value, **html_options)` only passes 2 positional arguments. If you get the same error message, it's from another method call.

Comment: I figured it out, thanks, for some reasons the keys of the hash needed to be all symbols, and that's why the dummy example worked. 

I changed the helper main call to: `<%= create_feature(level, my_helper(:pending).merge({class: 'mr-2'}).symbolize_keys) %>` and it works now